# How to exclude certain classes from being included in the code coverage? (Java)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I could already exclude the classes with sonar cube report by adding this in the  tag of my POM file.

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sonar.exclusions> 
            /src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/message/**/*
            ,
            /src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/security/jwt/**/*
            ,
            /src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/security/services/**/*
            ,
            /src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/controller/AuthRestAPIs.java
            ,
            /src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/controller/TestRestAPIs.java
        </sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>
```

However the same code when run locally to test the code coverage is not working at all.

Where do I set this up programmatically with Maven & Spring Boot ?.

I could already exclude the classes I want via the

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Excludes > [Class(es) to be
>   excluded]

or through

> Edit Configurations > Select Code Coverage tab > then adding the
>   package or class I want to be excluded or include only in the code
>   coverage report.

What I want is coding the classes to be excluded i.e in the pom file like I did with exclusion of code for sonar qube.

To make it short. How do I do this programmatically?.

Reason why I wanted to this programmatically is that, the above two steps I did to exclude the files from being reported in the code coverage is that no files was included in all of my project that I could push in the repository so that changes i made for exclusions will reflect in all those who will pull from the git repository. With no files or configurations added that I could push and reflect to all in the repo. THis means that my exclusions will only work locally and not work on others. Right?. So here I am asking for a way to do programmatically like putting the exclusions in a POM file.

Comment: You mean you want to do it in Java code instead of in the POM file?

Comment: yeap, so long as its programmatically. BTW, I already did this through the POM file but it only worked for Sonar Qubes Code Coverage and not locally. My IntelliJ still reports a very low code coverage.

Comment: The reason why I want this to be done programmaticallyis that I dont want scouring the settings of the project everytime just to add exclusions.Also it seems that it won't be carried over when push on git too as there was no files tracked in my project that was added when i did an exclusion through IntelliJs Run Configuration or Exclusions in Settings. hence I wanted to do it through a POM file or programmatically so that exclusion will be track by git and could be push that will take effect to those who pull from repo.

Comment: `it only worked for Sonar Qubes Code Coverage and not locally`. There's no way to know (the way your question is written) if there's any difference between your local config and the server config. `Not working at all` should be a description of what you have locally. What happens locally? Do you get any code coverage? Or do you get all the code covered and the sonar exclusions ignored? Do you use maven profiles? If yes, are the selected profiles different in the server and local?

Comment: i was getting almost the same code coverage with sonar and locally before I added the exclusions for sonar. However, the same it not true as now I don't have a matching code coverage report locally as my local code coverage report is still not excluding the classes I did for sonar. I don't know how to do this programmatically to exclude the same classes too locally. I don't know about the profiles you are saying, but so far that is my issue. That the classes I excluded for code coverage in sonar is not being excluded in the Local Code Coverage report with IntelliJ.

Comment: What I'm basically trying to do is have at least a very close coverage report with sonar since I'm going to exclude the same classes that I excluded with sonar.exclusion property in the pom file. As of the moment, my sonar code coverage reports 86% coverage, while locally I'm gettings 40% only which is a very big discrepancy. :/

Comment: Also, Is there anyway to have this configuration done in one go?. I mean, the exclusions for sonar coverage report will also reflect on the code coverage report locally made by IntelliJ?. Because as of the moment, it seems that the exclusions I made will only work with sonar. And I might have to really have a separate configuration which is okay for me anyway so long as that the coverage of sonar and intellij is the same.

Comment: Try to run the coverage test outside IntelliJ (just Maven) and check if it happens, just to discard the IDE as part of the issue

Comment: I just did with mvn test. And I'm getting a much lower report. The classes I want to be excluded is still on the report. :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are using Maven, you need to configure your exclusions in the jacoco plugin, which is used to capture the coverage statistics and pass it on to sonar.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.1</version>
<executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>snmaddula/app/domain/*.class</exclude>
        <exclude>snmaddula/app/exception/*.class</exclude>
        <exclude>snmaddula/app/filter/*.class</exclude>
        <exclude>snmaddula/app/App.class</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

References:

- [maven-jacoco-config](https://snmaddula.bitbucket.io/maven-jacoco-config)
- [gradle-jacoco-config](https://snmaddula.bitbucket.io/gradle-jacoco-config/)

Comment: How do i format the the directory in the exclude tag?. if i have this directory to exclude. [/src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/controller/AuthRestAPIs.java] 

As of the moment, I am using that very same directory to exclude, and it not making aany dent on the code coverage at all.

Comment: Hi joshua, to exclude a directory, use `<exclude>snmaddula/app/dto/**/*.class</exclude>`, this will exclude all the classes and subpackages of `dto` package.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the kind of answer that I was looking for really. But for now this will do for me. Still looking for a way to do this via the pom file, java or beans. thanks

**Solution:**

So if you did your exclusions in the Run Configuration of you project. That is through the 2nd step I mentioned in the question which is through

> Edit Configuration > Code Coverage.
>   [image]

---

And then actually add your exclusions. 
You would have just to tick the share text box and Click apply. 
The exclusions you made will be made available in your project directory under

> .idea/runConfigurations/[the xml file of the exclusions you made and
>   other run configurations].
>   [image]

And to be able to push this, just remove the

> .idea in your .gitignore file in git.
>   [image]

---

And then you'd be able to push the run configurations files in your repository for others to use. or export so that it won't have to be manually configure in the edit configurations of intellij.

PS:
This might affect the coverage report in your Sonarqube. You have to undo this and unpush from your repo the local run configuration to be able to use your sonar qubes class exclusions. For some reason in mine, it skipped all the exclusions  I made before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Since JaCoCo 0.8.2 you can use annotations to exclude classes or methods from coverage.

The name of the annotation should include Generated.
The retention policy of annotation should be runtime or class.

If you use project lombok, just use the annotation @Generated from package lombok.Generated.

If you don't use project lombok you can create your own annotation.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface Generated {
}
```

After creating this annotation just use it on classes or methods that you want to exclude from coverage report.

source: https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco-report-exclude

Answer (score 0):

In the `application.properties` you can do something like this:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/message/**/*, 
src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/security/jwt/**/*, 
src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/security/services/**/*,
src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/controller/AuthRestAPIs.java,
src/main/java/com/example/org/test/mainpackage/controller/TestRestAPIs.java
```

Also, other way will be login as admin in sonar and go to

> settings>Exclusions> Source File Exclusions- Add your packages here.
>   Restart the server.

Comment: Not working. The coverage report locally is still unchange. Even tried just having one class excluded, yet it was included in the coverage report with this.Any other ways of doing it?. I mean, I already have this done with sonar, I just need it to work locally. As of the moment my coverage reports locally and on sonar qube doesn't totally match at all as the exclusions I made for sonar qube is not setup for local test code coverage. :/

Comment: @iamjoshua have you restarted the server after the change ?

Comment: For my local compile?, yes I did.

Comment: @iamjoshua for sonar server-->  sonar.sh restart

Comment: nope, this is not a sonar related code coverage issue. I already fixed that. This is for the local coverage report being reported by IntelliJ when you run the project with Coverage.

Comment: `application.properties` is not recognized by Sounar plugin...so simple will not work

Answer (score 0):

By default, Intellij is using the Intellij IDEA as the default code coverage runner.

If you are using `jacoco`, then change this option to `JaCoCo`. The details of this can be found on the `jetbrains` website.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html

By following the above, all excluded classes defined in your `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>` will be taken into account and would match what you have in your remote `SonarQube` server's configuration.