# How to perform Tests for DTOs?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing

I am creating a class to store the tests of all `DTO` classes, but currently I only manage to cover 10% of the `coverage`. I need to know how to do the `@Tests` for the DTOs.

My `DTO`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActivityDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer version;

    @JsonProperty("working_days")
    private MonthWorkingDays workingDays;

}
```

My `Test` class:

```
@Test
    public void ActivityDTOTest() {
        ActivityDTO obj = BeanBuilder.builder(ActivityDTO.class).createRandomBean();
    }
```

This is the `coverage`:

[image]

**My problem**: I don't know how to test the `DTO` class, I'm testing with `assertEquals` but I don't know how to apply it. Can someone put what the Test class would be like for this DTO class and thus be able to replicate it in the other classes?

Comment: What do you like to test? For example that you set "version" and it holds that value?

Comment: I don't know how to test DTOs, so I would like to know the most common way to test DTOs. I wanted to know the best way in this case to then apply it to the other DTOs.

Comment: From a design pattern, I look at DTOs as containers for data that don't have behavior or functional logic. For that reason I look at DTOs as not being worth the time to test. That being said, what logic do your DTOs implement that needs testing? I don't see anything obvious from the snippets you've posted.

Comment: In the DTOs I store some fields that share similar entities. I have attached a screenshot with the coverage percentage of this DTO, it is what I want to solve.

Comment: I think this is a good example on howto NOT use code coverage. You see, all the methods that show 0 coverage there ... are **generated**. Worry about coverage for code that YOU wrote yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be subjective, but in general you should not test to increase the coverage, instead you should always think "what exactly" the test checks.

In a nutshell, there can be two things to be tested:

- A state of the object
- A behavior

Most of the tests usually (arguably, but at least this is what I usually do in my project) tend to check the behavior that is technically implemented as a business logic inside the methods.

Since the DTOs do not really have methods with the logic, you can only test the state of the object.

Another idea: there is no point in checking the code that you haven't written. So yes, following your example in the question, putting lombok annotations will generate some getters/setters/constructors - but its not your code, the proper handling of these annotations was supposed to be checked by lombok team itself.

What you can do if you really want to test DTOs is generate the one with some default values and check that its internal state indeed matches the expected. Something like this:

```
public class ActivityDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer version;

    // getters / setters maybe
}

@Test
public void test_state_is_correct() {
   ActivityDTO underTest  = new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION);
   assertThat(underTest.getId(), equalTo(SAMPLE_ID));
   assertThat(underTest.getVersion(), equalTo(SAMPLE_VERSION));
}

@Test
public void test_equals_two_objects_with_same_values() {
   ActivityDTO underTest  = new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION);
   assertThat(underTest, equalTo(new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION)); 
}

@Test
public void test_equals_two_objects_with_different_id() {
   ActivityDTO underTest  = new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION);
   assertThat(underTest, not(equalTo(new ActivityDTO(ANOTHER_SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION)); 
}


@Test
public void test_equals_two_objects_with_different_version() {
   ActivityDTO underTest  = new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_VERSION);
   assertThat(underTest, not(equalTo(new ActivityDTO(SAMPLE_ID, ANOTHER_SAMPLE_VERSION)); 
}

 ... test for toString()... and hashCode maybe, etc.
```

This will make the coverage tool happy for sure, but the real question is will it make your code better (more robust and less buggy, etc)?

One thing for sure - these tests are time consuming, boring, and probably give less value to the project. To overcome the frustration of the programmers who absolutely need to write these tests there are even tools for automatic testing of these simple java beans (DTO can be viewed as a java bean), to name a few:

https://github.com/codebox/javabean-tester

https://code.google.com/archive/p/junit-javabean-runner/

http://javabeantester.sourceforge.net/

Now the entirely different story is if you test the behavior of some service or DAO that, say, generates the DTO - these tests whether they're unit or integration tests are really needed. They'll also increase the coverage of the project (and maybe even will cover the code of the DTO, although its not their primary goal), but I would suggest to start writing these tests first.

Comment: All this creating unit tests for DTOs is simple curiosity because I did not know how they were done and I want to test. In this case I have used JavaBeanTester for the DTOs and it works well and is faster than the one I currently have, but there is still coverage level to cover, since it gets the same percentage. The @Data annotation is in yellow, could that be why? Is it possible to test that annotation? If so, how do I test that annotation?

Comment: As I said, the annotation is of lombok, so you dont test is. In general you shouldn't test the code that is not yours...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the best practice but AFAIK you should exclude the DTO classes from the configuration and you don't have to write unit test for them.

If you are using JaCoCo plugin, you better check this out: [How to exclude certain classes from being included in the code coverage? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017862/637724)

Comment: But I don't want to exclude them, I just want to know how to test DTO classes?

Comment: @sinfryd95 The answer is: there is no simple answer to your question. What makes you *think* that DTOs can/should be tested like ordinary other classes?

Comment: Okay then from what I have seen it is best not to test the DTOs but to exclude them from the tests from the pom, right? Now i will try to do that

Comment: I am trying to exclude DTOs using Jacoco, I have added the following xml: ``<configuration>
<excludes>
<exclude> snmaddula / app / dto / ** / *. class </exclude>
</excludes>
</configuration>``. Then I have run ``mvn clean test`` but it keeps doing the DTOs, what am I doing wrong? What do I have to change in the xml?